# SQL query Lastname, first name within string

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Hey all I have a string that is formatted like so:

```
Bob Barker - The Game Show Host
Bill Gates - A Programmer
Steve Jobs - The Apple Guy
```

The above is in a row called rowNameOcu.

What I am looking to do is query that and present it like this:

```
Barker, Bob - The Game Show Host
Gates, Bill - A Programmer
Jobs, Steve - The Apple Guy
```

I am sure I could look for the **-** and then grab everything to the right of that, but then how can I reverse the name after that?

Any help would be great!

Comment: What programming language are you using?  How is this related to SQL (unless the 3 strings are 3 cells from a database query)? It sounds like simple string manipulation of the text.  Can you show the code you've written so far and where you are stuck?

Comment: What do you expect the result for `Billy Bob Thornton` to be?  What about `Benicio del Toro`?

Comment: If you don't have separate fields for this data. Good luck, names are one of the trickiest things when it comes to data, since there are pretty much no rules.

Comment: And _why_ do you need the name reversed?

Comment: Google and learn about PATINDEX() and SUBSTRING().

Comment: @SteveFrancisco its SQL 2008. That information i typed above is in one row.

Comment: @DStanley Its how they designed the database back in the *old days* and therefore, we have to maintain it and hack it to do simple things that if done right in the first place, we wouldn't need to hack.

Comment: @jbg Luckly this particual data does not have 3 names (first middle last). It only has **First and Last**.

Comment: @All No need to down-vote a legit question....

Comment: @StealthRT I'm saying why do you need last name first?  Why not just use the manes as-is?

Comment: @DStanley Because that was the request from the end user.

Comment: You should probably ask the end user also to request you to fix your table so that you would have different columns for first & last name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an option:

```
SELECT  
SUBSTRING(rowNameOcu,CHARINDEX(' ',rowNameOcu),CHARINDEX(' ',right(rowNameOcu,len(rowNameOcu) - CHARINDEX(' ',rowNameOcu)))) + ', ' + left(rowNameOcu,CHARINDEX(' ',rowNameOcu)) + RIGHT(rowNameOcu, CHARINDEX('-',reverse(rowNameOcu)))  
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: That does do what i needed to do... however, its not putting it into ASC order by that last name now.. its still using the first name as order by.

Comment: You can add this to the end:

`ORDER BY SUBSTRING(rowNameOcu,CHARINDEX(' ',rowNameOcu),CHARINDEX(' ',right(rowNameOcu,len(rowNameOcu) - CHARINDEX(' ',rowNameOcu)))) asc`

Comment: Ah, adding **AS LastFirstName** to the end of the **reverse([ITACRep])))** fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING`:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7d/2178/0)**

```
Declare @t table ( [Name] varchar(100) );

insert into @t ( Name )
VALUES ( 'Bob Barker - The Game Show Host' ),
      ('Bill Gates - A Programmer'),
      ('Steve Jobs - The Apple Guy') ;

;WITH cte AS
(SELECT
    [Name],
    [Title] = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-', [Name]) > 0 THEN
                       SUBSTRING([Name],CHARINDEX('-',[Name])+1, ( LEN([Name]) - CHARINDEX(' ',[Name])+1) )
                       ELSE NULL
                   END,   
    [FIRST_NAME] = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', [Name]) > 0 THEN
                      LEFT([Name],CHARINDEX(' ',[Name])-1)
                      ELSE[Name]
                    END,
    [LAST_NAME] = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', [Name]) > 0 THEN
                       SUBSTRING([Name],CHARINDEX(' ',[Name])+1, (CHARINDEX('-',[name]) - CHARINDEX(' ', [name])-1) )
                       ELSE NULL
                   END 
FROM @t
)
SELECT [Last_Name] + ', ' + [First_Name] + ' - ' + [Title]
FROM cte;
```

*Warning: They may be edge cases when it fails like 3 part name or title with `-`*